# How to test Promise then method

Tags: angular, testing, promise

How do I test the code inside the then() method of a Promise. I do not see code coverage for the code inside the then(..) method of my code. My unit test passes and throws no errors, but when I look at line coverage, the code inside toPromise.then(//this code) is not covered. How do I test that code.

```
//service file
getDataFromAPI(num: string): Promise<Model> {
  return this._http
   .get<Model>('url')
   .toPromise()
   .then(resolve => {
       const { item1, item2, item3 } = resolve;
       return { item1, item2, item3 };
  });
}


//unit test
describe('getDataFromAPI', () => {
it('should get data', () => {

  const service: Service = TestBed.get(Service);
  const httpClientGetSpy = jest.spyOn(httpClient, 'get');

  service.getDataFromAPI(num).then(response => {
    expect(response.item1).toEqual('one');
    expect(response.item2).toEqual('two');
    expect(response.item3).toEqual('three');
  });

  expect(httpClientGetSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
});
```

Comment: As I understand, you wish to test the callback from .then(), which essentially extracts item1, item2, item3 from the Promise result and return them. You can extract that callback as another function and assert that it destructures the Promise result and returns the expected values on an object.

Comment: Yes correct, would i just assign the service.getDataFromAPI to a var in my unit test, and then do an assertion on that?

Comment: Assuming you name your callback extractItems, you can assert as follows: ` it('should extract the correct items', () => { /* define your mockData and expectedResult*/   const result = extractItems(mockData); expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);   })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of asynchronous task. Your test end before promise so `then` callback is never called.

Just change your test to handle `async`

**Method 1**

Use `fakeAsync` provided by Angular : https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync

```
it('should get data', fakeAsync(() => {

  const service: Service = TestBed.get(Service);
  const httpClientGetSpy = jest.spyOn(httpClient, 'get');

  service.getDataFromAPI(num).then(response => {
    expect(response.item1).toEqual('one');
    expect(response.item2).toEqual('two');
    expect(response.item3).toEqual('three');
  });

  expect(httpClientGetSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

**Method 2**

Use `async/await` from ES2016 : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

```
it('should get data', async() => {

  const service: Service = TestBed.get(Service);
  const httpClientGetSpy = jest.spyOn(httpClient, 'get');

  let response = await service.getDataFromAPI(num);
  expect(response.item1).toEqual('one');
  expect(response.item2).toEqual('two');
  expect(response.item3).toEqual('three');

  expect(httpClientGetSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

**Method 3**

Handle when test should be ended with `done` function :

```
it('should get data', (done) => {

  const service: Service = TestBed.get(Service);
  const httpClientGetSpy = jest.spyOn(httpClient, 'get');

  service.getDataFromAPI(num).then(response => {
    expect(response.item1).toEqual('one');
    expect(response.item2).toEqual('two');
    expect(response.item3).toEqual('three');
    done();
  });

  expect(httpClientGetSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```